# Azure Site Recover - Powershell Create Recovery Plan from Vmware to Azure

Tags: azure, powershell, vmware

I have set up an ASR appliance in in VMware and I am replicating VMs to Azure.
I want to create Recovery Plans with powershell instead of through the Portal.

When I get the fabric, there is only one fabric:

```
$asrFabric = Get-AzRecoveryServicesAsrFabric

Name                  : my-rsv-vmwarefabric
FriendlyName          : my-rsv-vmwarefabric
ID                    : /Subscriptions/59fe8180-18f2-4d05-aa68-d2836a9c9157/resourceGroups/MyResourcesGrp/providers/Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/my-rsv/replicationFabrics/my-rsv-vmwarefabric
Type                  : Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/replicationFabrics
FabricType            : InMageRcm
SiteIdentifier        : f2ed57c5-397b-58ad-9863-9e8cc0d16e57
FabricSpecificDetails : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.RecoveryServices.SiteRecovery.ASRInMageRcmFabricSpecificDetails
```

However the command to create a new Recovery plan is looking for 2 fabrics, PrimaryFabric and RecoveryFabric

```
New-AzRecoveryServicesAsrRecoveryPlan -Name $RecoveryPlanName -ReplicationProtectedItem $rpi -PrimaryFabric $PrimaryFabric -RecoveryFabric $RecoveryFabric
```

I assume the -RecoveryFabric is the target and so my $asrfabric above.
It seems to me the -PrimaryFabric has to refer to VMware, but I don't know how to get it, in order to supply it to the command.

Anyone with any experience or ideas on how to run this command properly to create a VMware to Azure RecoveryPlan?